# Calling structures in C

Tags: c, struct

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct {
   double x, y;
} point_t ;


typedef struct {
    point_t a, b, c;
} triangle_t;

int read_point(point_t * const point) {
    int status = scanf(" (&lf,&lf)", &point_t.x, &point_t.y);
    return(status);
}
```

I'm trying to read an x and y coordinate that the user enters for the vertexes of a triangle (Points a, b and c.) However, I'm getting a weird error underlining both instances of "point_t" in the scanf function.

> Type name is not allowed.

What's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change it to:

```
int status = scanf(" (%lf,%lf)", &(point->x), &(point->y));
```

Remember to use the variable name `point`, not the type name `point_t`. It also important to note that you must use the operator `->` on pointer types (it is equivalent to dereferencing it and then using the member operator [`p->x == (*p).x`]).

Comment: I would strongly suggest also changing `&lf` to `%lf` ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point :) Wasn't even looking at that part.

Comment: this solved my problem! Guess I was looking at this the wrong way. Thanks fro your help!

Answer (score -3):

try this code

```
typedef struct {
   double x;
   double y;
} point_t ;


typedef struct {
    point_t a;
    point_t b
    point_t c;
} triangle_t;

int read_point(point_t * point) {
    int status = scanf(" (&lf,&lf)", point->x, point->y);
    return(status);
}
```

I think in struct, you should declare each field with it's type; multiple declaration as `int x,y` doesn't work.
Secondly, you are passing a pointer so to access you should use the name of your argument ( "point" is this case) this way `point->field` or `(*point).field` and not `&point` !